# How can we add time delay in java programming?

Tags: java, recursion, time

I have this program :

```
import javax.swing.*;

public static void main()
{
    try {
        String stringyInp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null , "Enter your number" ) ; 
        int input = Integer.parseInt(stringyInp) ;
    }catch(Exception e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null ,"Enter only numerical values") ; //i want here to add a time delay of 3 seconds!How?
       main(); 
    }
    System.out.print( FACTORIAL(input)) ;


}// instance variables - replace the example below with your own



 public static int FACTORIAL(int number )
{
     if (number == 0){
         return 1 ;
        }
        else {

    return FACTORIAL(number-1) * number ;

}
```

So how can we add time delay ,how can we execute an instruction with a delay of 3 seconds?? I would like in this program to add a delay of 3 seconds or 2 seconds...

Comment: Thread.sleep()....you can use a timer instead calling main

Comment: No, don't use `Thread.sleep(...)` unless you do so in a background thread. Google and use a Swing Timer. Also, your code will not compile as it's missing critical components. Please strive to post real code whenever possible. The compiler is unforgiving, and so you should be too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this code.

```
   try {
     Thread.sleep(1000);
   } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
```